# Search in Word "headings" only

Tags: microsoft-word, search

In Microsoft Word, is there any way to search for text in the "headings" of a document only?

​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​I'm currently using Word 2007 and 2010.

Comment: Apologies. Keep forgetting my work Laptop runs off a different Word package to my home system. Unless someone else answers I will get some screen grabs and post when I return in an hour or so.

Comment: It would be helpful to have a visual of the document.  Do the headings have unique line spacing? If so, you could ask Word to search for paragraph formatting if, for example, you had spacing of say 18 pt before and 12 after for all headings.

Answer (score 3):

In Word's Advanced Search (click More) you can search within style sets.

Select Format, then select the styles you want to search in

[image: Style Based Searches]

*In this example the search will only find the word Heading in the Heading elements, and will skip the word Heading in the body element.*

Comment: Thanks. Though this information might be helpful in certain cases - it doesn't allow me to search in all headings, only in a specific heading level. (Besides being lots of work to get to.)

Answer (score 0):

HOWTO Search only the Headers:
In MSWord\References tab - Add the 'Table of Contents' to the beginning of the document, then do a standard search (which will start at the beginning of the document which is where your table of contents and that includes only your headers)... so searching starts with the Table of Contents, which only includes Headers.

BACKGROUND:
This fix worked for me using Word2016.
I have large documents and use Headers and the Navigation Pane to organize my data and sometimes I want to search my doc, but want to return results ONLY from the headers... not the general text from the body. (Very useful for querying generic terms and being able to limit results to only the headers). I usually use the 'Navigation Pane' to move around to different sections in the document. I never really use the Table of Contents at the beginning of the document, but has been useful to add the Table of Contents just for searching ONLY the headers.